# Efficient the handling of multiple object events. Kotlin Android

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

I finding out that my code is not very *efficient* (android app).
the general perpose of the app is to complete tasks.
I'm attaching the code, and you will find out its not super professional.

Main_Activity.kt:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, NotefictisService::class.java)
        startService(serviceIntent)
        val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreference.edit()
        var points = sharedPreference.getInt("points", 0)
        val text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.PointsText)
        val textnum1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        val textnum2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView2)
        val textnum3: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        val textnum4: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        val textnum5: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView5)
        val textnum6: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView6)
        val textnum7: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView7)
        val textnum8: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView8)
        val textnum9: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView9)
        val textnum10: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView10)
        val textnum11: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView11)
        val textnum12: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView12)
        val textnum13: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView13)
        val textnum14: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView14)
        val textnum15: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView15)
        val textnum16: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView16)
        val textnum17: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView17)
        val textnum18: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView18)
        val cb1: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)
        val cb2: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)
        val cb3: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox3)
        val cb4: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox4)
        val cb5: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox5)
        val cb6: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox6)
        val cb7: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox7)
        val cb8: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox8)
        val cb9: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox9)
        val cb10: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox10)
        val cb11: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox11)
        val cb12: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox12)
        val cb13: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox13)
        val cb14: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox14)
        val cb15: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox15)
        val cb16: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox16)
        val cb17: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox17)
        val cb18: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox18)
        val group1 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more1)
        val group2: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more2)
        val group3 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more3)
        val group4 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more4)
        val group5 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more5)
        val group6 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more6)
        val group7 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more7)
        val group8 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more8)
        val group9 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more9)
        val group10 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more10)
        val group11 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more11)
        val group12 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more12)
        val group13 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more13)
        val group14 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more14)
        val group15 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more15)
        val group16 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more16)
        val group17 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more17)
        val group18 : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.more18)
        val task1 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_1)
        val task2 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_2)
        val task3 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_3)
        val task4 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_4)
        val task5 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_5)
        val task6 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_6)
        val task7 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_7)
        val task8 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_8)
        val task9 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_9)
        val task10 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_10)
        val task11 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_11)
        val task12 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_12)
        val task13 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_13)
        val task14 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_14)
        val task15 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_15)
        val task16 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_16)
        val task17 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_17)
        val task18 : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Task_18)
        val add: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.add)
        task1.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task1" , true)
        task2.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task2" , false)
        task3.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task3" , false)
        task4.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task4" , false)
        task5.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task5" , false)
        task6.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task6" , false)
        task7.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task7" , false)
        task8.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task8" , false)
        task9.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task9" , false)
        task10.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task10" , false)
        task11.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task11" , false)
        task12.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task12" , false)
        task13.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task13" , false)
        task14.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task14" , false)
        task15.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task15" , false)
        task16.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task16" , false)
        task17.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task17" , false)
        task18.isVisible = sharedPreference.getBoolean("task18" , false)
        text.text = points.toString()
        cb1.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb1e" , false)
        cb2.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb2e" , false)
        cb3.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb3e" , false)
        cb4.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb4e" , false)
        cb5.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb5e" , false)
        cb6.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb6e" , false)
        cb7.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb7e" , false)
        cb8.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb8e" , false)
        cb9.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb9e" , false)
        cb10.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb10e" , false)
        cb11.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb11e" , false)
        cb12.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb12e" , false)
        cb13.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb13e" , false)
        cb14.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb14e" , false)
        cb15.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb15e" , false)
        cb16.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb16e" , false)
        cb17.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb17e" , false)
        cb18.isChecked = sharedPreference.getBoolean("cb18e" , false)
        cb1.text = sharedPreference.getString("name1", "")
        cb2.text = sharedPreference.getString("name2", "")
        cb3.text = sharedPreference.getString("name3", "")
        cb4.text = sharedPreference.getString("name4", "")
        cb5.text = sharedPreference.getString("name5", "")
        cb6.text = sharedPreference.getString("name6", "")
        cb7.text = sharedPreference.getString("name7", "")
        cb8.text = sharedPreference.getString("name8", "")
        cb9.text = sharedPreference.getString("name9", "")
        cb10.text = sharedPreference.getString("name10", "")
        cb11.text = sharedPreference.getString("name11", "")
        cb12.text = sharedPreference.getString("name12", "")
        cb13.text = sharedPreference.getString("name13", "")
        cb14.text = sharedPreference.getString("name14", "")
        cb15.text = sharedPreference.getString("name15", "")
        cb16.text = sharedPreference.getString("name16", "")
        cb17.text = sharedPreference.getString("name17", "")
        cb18.text = sharedPreference.getString("name18", "")
        val num1 = sharedPreference.getInt("num1", 1)
        val num2 = sharedPreference.getInt("num2", 1)
        val num3 = sharedPreference.getInt("num3", 1)
        val num4 = sharedPreference.getInt("num4", 1)
        val num5 = sharedPreference.getInt("num5", 1)
        val num6 = sharedPreference.getInt("num6", 1)
        val num7 = sharedPreference.getInt("num7", 1)
        val num8 = sharedPreference.getInt("num8", 1)
        val num9 = sharedPreference.getInt("num9", 1)
        val num10 = sharedPreference.getInt("num10", 1)
        val num11 = sharedPreference.getInt("num11", 1)
        val num12 = sharedPreference.getInt("num12", 1)
        val num13 = sharedPreference.getInt("num13", 1)
        val num14 = sharedPreference.getInt("num14", 1)
        val num15 = sharedPreference.getInt("num15", 1)
        val num16 = sharedPreference.getInt("num16", 1)
        val num17 = sharedPreference.getInt("num17", 1)
        val num18 = sharedPreference.getInt("num18", 1)
        textnum1.text = num1.toString()
        textnum2.text = num2.toString()
        textnum3.text = num3.toString()
        textnum4.text = num4.toString()
        textnum5.text = num5.toString()
        textnum6.text = num6.toString()
        textnum7.text = num7.toString()
        textnum8.text = num8.toString()
        textnum9.text = num9.toString()
        textnum10.text = num10.toString()
        textnum11.text = num11.toString()
        textnum12.text = num12.toString()
        textnum13.text = num13.toString()
        textnum14.text = num14.toString()
        textnum15.text = num15.toString()
        textnum16.text = num16.toString()
        textnum17.text = num17.toString()
        textnum18.text = num18.toString()
        add.setOnClickListener {
            if (!task2.isVisible){
                task2.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task2" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task3.isVisible){
                task3.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task3" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task4.isVisible){
                task4.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task4" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task5.isVisible){
                task5.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task5" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task6.isVisible){
                task6.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task6" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task7.isVisible){
                task7.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task7" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task8.isVisible){
                task8.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task8" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task9.isVisible){
                task9.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task9" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task10.isVisible){
                task10.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task10" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task11.isVisible){
                task11.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task11" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task12.isVisible){
                task12.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task12" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task13.isVisible){
                task13.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task13" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task14.isVisible){
                task14.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task14" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task15.isVisible){
                task15.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task15" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task16.isVisible){
                task16.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task16" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task17.isVisible){
                task17.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task17" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else if (!task18.isVisible){
                task18.isVisible = true
                editor.putBoolean("task18" , true)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        group1.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 1)
            editor.putString("mode" , "modify")
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group2.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 2)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group3.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 3)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group4.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 4)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group5.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 5)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group6.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 6)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group7.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 7)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group8.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 8)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group9.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 9)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group10.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 10)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group11.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 11)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group12.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 12)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group13.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 13)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group14.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 14)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group15.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 15)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group16.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 16)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group17.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 17)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        group18.setOnClickListener{
            editor.putInt("cbEditNow" , 18)
            editor.apply()
            val intent = Intent(this, EditCbs::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    points += num1
                    text.text = points.toString()
                    editor.putInt("points", points)
                    editor.putBoolean("cb1e", true)
                    editor.apply()
                    }
                else{
                    points -= num1
                    text.text = points.toString()
                    editor.putInt("points", points)
                    editor.putBoolean("cb1e", false)
                    editor.apply()
                }
            }
        cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num2
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb2e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num2
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb2e", false)
                editor.apply()
                }
            }
        cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num3
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb3e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num3
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb3e", false)
                editor.apply()
                }
            }
        cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num4
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb4e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num4
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb4e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb5.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num5
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb5e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num5
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb5e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb6.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num6
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb6e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num6
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb6e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb7.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num7
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb7e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num7
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb7e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb8.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num8
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb8e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num8
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb8e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb9.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num9
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb9e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num9
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb9e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb10.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num10
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb10e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num10
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb10e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb11.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num11
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb11e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num11
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb11e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb12.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num12
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb12e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num12
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb12e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb13.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num13
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb13e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num13
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb13e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb14.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num14
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb14e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num14
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb14e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb15.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num15
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb15e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num15
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb15e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb16.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num16
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb16e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num16
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb16e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb17.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num17
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb17e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num17
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb17e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
        cb18.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                points += num18
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb18e", true)
                editor.apply()
            }
            else{
                points -= num18
                text.text = points.toString()
                editor.putInt("points", points)
                editor.putBoolean("cb18e", false)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you got it.
and this can handle 18 checkboxes...
please can someone help to short it for easy to handle code that support infinate checkboxes?
(there's textViwes, for displaying a certain num that added in cbEdit activity.)

im expecting for handling click events by id's, and no need for all the "val"s in the start.

Comment: One word answer: RecyclerView